# How to prevent error messages for WebResource.axd errors from appearing in the Application log?

Tags: asp.net, logging, error-handling

I am running an ASP.NET web application under IIS 7.5 and my Application log is full of errors like this:

> Event code: 3012
>
> Event message: An error occurred processing a web or script resource
>   request. The resource identifier failed to decrypt.
>
> ...
>
> Exception information:
>
> ```
> Exception type: HttpException 
>
> Exception message: Unable to validate data.
> ```
>
> at
>   System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean
>   fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length,
>   Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean useLegacyMode, IVType ivType,
>   Boolean signData)
>
> ...
>
> Request information:
>
> ```
> Request URL: http://www.mysite.com/WebResource.axd?d=l0ngstr1ng0fl3tt3rs4ndd1g1ts 
>
> Request path: /WebResource.axd
> ```
>
> ...

How can I prevent them from appearing?  As per [this link](http://blog.beacontechnologies.com/prevent-errors-from-being-written-to-application-event-log/), I have added the following code to my Global.asax file:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Code that runs when an *unhandled* error occurs
  //// get reference to the source of the exception chain
  Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
  string message = ex.Message;
  string path = Request.Path;
  // ignore the following:
  //   errors due to bots trying AXD URLs
  //   errors due to <doNastyThings /> tags in the URLs
  if (
    (ex is HttpException && (path.StartsWith("/WebResource.axd") || path.StartsWith("/ScriptResource.axd"))) ||
    (ex is HttpException && message.StartsWith("A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client"))
    )
  {
    // clear the error *to prevent it from appearing in the main Application log*
    Server.ClearError();
    // need to manually direct to the error page, since it will no longer happen automatically once the error has been cleared
    Response.Redirect("/Error");
  }
}
```

The second group of errors (for potentially dangerous requests) are being caught and repressed by this code; the WebResource.axd errors have already been written to the Application log by the time this code is executed, however.  I'm presuming that's because the AXD handler works differently to the standard ASPX handler in terms of error logging (but I have no idea what to do as a result).

All help gratefully received!

Comment: it looks like the webresource.axd is directly requested without the SSL. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Cerveser: I didn't, no -- I learnt to live with it :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I only get this error when I get requests from the Bingbot crawler. You can check if it's the bing bot [here](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/verify-bingbot)

So I added this in my robots.txt file. It doesn't work if you don't add specifically that it's the user-agent Bingbot

```
User-agent: bingbot
Disallow: /ScriptResource.axd  
Disallow: /combinescriptshandler.axd  
Disallow: /WebResource.axd
```

Comment: Nice one -- thanks very much for that.  In fact it was the Baidu spider: same solution, though!

Comment: Actually, it turns out that Baidu doesn't obey robots.txt so I have blocked it in the web.config file instead.

Comment: Bing bot doesn't obey the robots.txt either, so what's the use of the robots.txt than?

Answer (score 2):

/WebResource.axd is generally requested because a page contains a link to it, often an img src:

```
<img ... src="/WebResource.axd..." />
```

usually generated from an ASP.NET WebControl, e.g. a Menu control.

I would recommend you locate the page that contains the WebResource.axd reference, see how and why it's being generated, and why it's invalid.  For example, you can look at the IIS server logs to find which page immediately precedes the WebResource.axd request, or you can add your own logging to Application_BeginRequest.

Once you've found out the offending page, and identified which control on the page is generating the request, ask again here.

I've seen this in the past in a static HTML page which contains HTML (e.g. a menu) that was copied and pasted from a rendered ASPX page.  The request is not valid in a static HTML page, and the fix was simply to remove the offending img element.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Joe.  In my site, however, there is no explicit reference to WebResource.axd (nor any other AXD file) on any page; the only places the string "WebResource.axd" exists are the Global.asax file, the web.config file and a few third-party .js files (written by Telerik).  I rather thought it was a bot randomly requesting resources.  Indeed, if I put the WebResource.axd URL in myself directly, my code still writes the error to the Application log.  This is the thing I want to avoid!

Comment: @EdGraham - "there is no explicit reference to WebResource.axd ..." - yes, but if you find the page just before the .axd request, you'll be able to look what it is on the page that's requesting it.  E.g. the page may have one of the third party .js files which is erroneously requesting it.  I'd be surprised to see a valid request for it in a static .js file, since I don't see how the .js file would know how to generate a valid querystring.  With Fiddler and possibly inserting alert statements in the .js files, you should be able to work out exactly where the offending request is generated.

Comment: Thanks again, Joe -- but we're missing the point.  I'm not trying to eliminate the request for WebResource.axd; I'm trying to prevent the resulting error from being written to the Application log.  I'm wondering whether I can modify Global.asax or alter the web.config file in some way to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

These errors can be caused when Bingbot does something really stupid and lowercases the URL it requests.

I don't know quite why it does this, but the URL listed in the event log is in fact linked from the affected page - only with some uppercase letters! For example, actual link in the HTML:

```
https://example.com/WebResource.axd?d=[...]13QzJRP4goegQTwpQQcl[...]
```

Same link as requested by bingbot:

```
https://example.com/webresource.axd?d=[...]13qzjrp4goegqtwpqqcl[...]
```

Oh well... these are clearly harmless errors to be ignored or suppressed.